# Optimization of an SQL Query on multiple tables with Left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a custom mysql query which is running fine and showing the output I want, but it is currently taking a lot of time as data volumes are high.

So, please help me in optimizing query run time.

```
SELECT t.*, te + tc + tt AS total, (te + tc + tt)/7 AS weekly_Avg
FROM (SELECT t2.first_name, COUNT(DISTINCT emails.id) AS te,
        COUNT(DISTINCT calls.id) AS tc, COUNT(DISTINCT tasks.id) AS tt
      FROM users AS t2
      LEFT JOIN emails
        ON t2.id = emails.assigned_user_id
        AND emails.date_entered >= '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
        AND emails.date_entered <= '2014-06-30 00:00:00'
      LEFT JOIN calls
        ON t2.id = calls.assigned_user_id
        AND calls.date_entered >= '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
        AND calls.date_entered <= '2014-06-30 00:00:00'
      LEFT JOIN tasks
        ON t2.id = tasks.assigned_user_id
        AND tasks.date_entered >= '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
        AND tasks.date_entered <= '2014-06-30 00:00:00')
      WHERE t2.id IN ('1', '2')
      GROUP BY t2.id) t
```

Comment: Can you give your table structure example with data and then its expected output.

Comment: Also, any indexes that are on the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many calls / emails / tasks are there per user in the time period? This query is effectively doing a cross join of the results, so if there were (say) 100 of each per user, that is giving you 1000000 records per user and then sorting out the unique ones within that list.

If so it might be easier to have a sub query to get each count and join the results together.

```
SELECT t . * ,te+tc+tt as total , (,te+tc+tt)/7 as weekly_Avg
FROM 
(
    SELECT t2.first_name, emails_count AS te, calls_count AS tc, tasks_count AS tt
    FROM  `users` AS t2
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT assigned_user_id, COUNT( emails.id ) AS emails_count
        FROM emails 
        WHERE emails.assigned_user_id IN ( '1',  '2')
        AND (emails.date_entered >=  '2014-03-20 00:00:00' 
        AND emails.date_entered <=  '2014-06-30 00:00:00')
        GROUP BY assigned_user_id
    ) sub_emails
    ON t2.id = sub_emails.assigned_user_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT assigned_user_id, COUNT( calls.id ) AS calls_count
        FROM calls 
        WHERE calls.assigned_user_id IN ( '1',  '2')
        AND (calls.date_entered >=  '2014-03-20 00:00:00' 
        AND calls.date_entered <=  '2014-06-30 00:00:00')
        GROUP BY assigned_user_id
    ) sub_calls
    ON t2.id = sub_calls.assigned_user_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT assigned_user_id, COUNT( tasks.id ) AS tasks_count
        FROM tasks 
        WHERE tasks.assigned_user_id IN ( '1',  '2')
        AND (tasks.date_entered >=  '2014-03-20 00:00:00' 
        AND tasks.date_entered <=  '2014-06-30 00:00:00')
        GROUP BY assigned_user_id
    ) sub_tasks
    ON t2.id = sub_tasks.assigned_user_id
    WHERE t2.id IN ('1',  '2')
)t
```

Note, the checks for user_id within the sub queries are not strictly necessary, but should speed things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but when in te+tc+tt if any value say(tt) is null then result is null. e.g. if 30+10+(0 or null) then result is null , but it should show 40 as result , can you please suggest how to achieve this

Comment: You could use `IFNULL(te, 0)+IFNULL(tc, 0)+IFNULL(tt, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I see you're joining tables and filtering afterward. For instance:

```
SELECT t2.first_name, COUNT( DISTINCT emails.id ) AS te, COUNT( DISTINCT calls.id ) AS tc, COUNT( DISTINCT tasks.id ) AS tt
FROM  `users` AS t2
LEFT JOIN emails ON t2.id = emails.assigned_user_id
AND (

emails.date_entered >=  '2014-03-20 00:00:00'
AND emails.date_entered <=  '2014-06-30 00:00:00'
)
```

You should rather do something like this:

```
SELECT t2.first_name, COUNT( DISTINCT emails.id ) AS te, COUNT( DISTINCT calls.id ) AS tc, COUNT( DISTINCT tasks.id ) AS tt
FROM  `users` AS t2
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT FIELDS_YOU_NEED 
 FROM `emails` 
 WHERE date_entered >=  '2014-03-20 00:00:00' AND date_entered <=  '2014-06-30 00:00:00'
 ) AS emails2 

ON t2.id = emails2.assigned_user_id
```

This way you'll reduce significantly the time consumed joining tables.

Comment: This is bad advice.  MySQL materializes subqueries and loses the ability to use indexes.